# Ionic 6, CI Property progress is not allowed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

My project, with name in lowercase, compiles and creates the apk, but in VStudio it indicates a problem that I have not been able to solve, **Property progress is not allowed**:

```
code in angular.json: 
 "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
```

---

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/ionic/prueba/angular.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Property progress is not allowed.",
    "startLineNumber": 86,
    "startColumn": 15,
    "endLineNumber": 86,
    "endColumn": 25
}]
```

I send additional information, thank you very much !!!

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (C:\Users\Guille\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.14

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.1

   OS                : Windows 10
```